# How to save the generated tone to the audio file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tone-generator

I have read the tone generator in ios from http://www.eslacker.com/?p=198. After that, I want to improve it to can save the tone generator to the audio file. So , the tone generator can be ringtone. How can I got it? Thanks before :D

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have it upload the file as simple PCM to your website for conversion, allow the user to download it to his/her computer, and tell them how to sync it, but there is not a chance in hell apple would make it easy to make ringtones with *only* an iphone. After all, they make money by only letting you easily make ringtones from songs you buy on iTunes, but won't let you use ones ripped from CDs without lots of workarounds. You can do it from a desktop by cropping the sound to 30 seconds, converting it to AAC, and giving it the file extension `.m4r`, and then importing it into itunes and syncing. I have no idea how to do it without a jailbroken iDevice that can access the root filesystem and change the `.plist` files and database files that control synced media. You could run `ffmpeg` on a webserver and use that to make and crop ringtones. Or port and include ffmpeg inside your app and have it convert it and save it in the space that you can share between apps and manage with itunes.